# 2004 renault megane grand scenic ii

Tags: electrical, wiring, renault, megane

I am currently having an issue with my car when I try to start I have the follow messages low oil pressure,  low battery,  parking brake fault I have inspected all wiring fuses in engine bay  all fine I found a melted connection on the upc fuse box which has been replace and the connection replaced, new battery but the fault is still there does anyone know where there are any more fuses Or relaysany where else in the car regardless of what they are for I want to check the as much of the wiring for water ingress as possible

Comment: This may be stating the obvious but did you clear the fault codes after doing the work on the fuse box etc?

Comment: Yes I did clear any fault code there where none showing in dtc

Comment: I have arranged and auto Electrician to come and take a look on Monday and failing that I'm buying a full ecu kit and changing it engine ecu,  body ecu, steering lock unit, key card

Answer (score -2):

Artificial inteligence could reprogram all the electronics on your renault scenic car ignition key, electric windows alarm sistem etc.

Comment: That would violate all the safety rules in force in the motoring world.  CENELEC, MISRA, EN50128 to name but three.  If that were even remotely possible, all such cars would be mandatorily off the road within a heartbeat.